# How to display xml element name in rtf template using BI Publisher?

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, oraclereports

I have an xml output given below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<XXBAXY_INHOUSE_REJ_DT>
<LIST_Q_DATA>
<Q_DATA>
<PROCESS>LPC</PROCESS>
<PART_NAME>PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29</PART_NAME>
<OK_QTY>12420</OK_QTY>
<Rejection_Reason>5</Rejection_Reason>
</Q_DATA>
<Q_DATA>
<PROCESS>LPC</PROCESS>
<PART_NAME>TU 5 CYL. HEAD (IRAN KHUDO)</PART_NAME>
<OK_QTY>1425</OK_QTY>
<Rejection_Reason>5</Rejection_Reason>
</Q_DATA>
</LIST_Q_DATA>
</XXBAXY_INHOUSE_REJ_DT>
```

Now I need to make an rtf template whose output should be as such:-

```
PROCESS   PART_NAME                             OK_QTY       REJECTION_REASON
LPC      PEGEOUT 1.8 CYLINDER HEAD CASTING H29   12420             5
LPC      TU 5 CYL. HEAD (IRAN KHUDO)             1425              5
```

The main catch is Rejection Reason element is dynamic.It means element Rejection Reason keeps on changing.Like next instance it may be Casting damage instead of Rejection Reason element.

Comment: Completely dynamic, or one of a known set of possible values? Would a SQL query that converts the XML to a relational table work - not sure what restrictions the reports/rtf side puts on what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alex-Not completely dynamic.Only Rejection Reason element is dynamic in this case.Process,Part_name,ok_qty are fixed elements.Yes SQL query is generating dynamic xml.